# Убрать одинарные кавычки из кортежа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан кортеж вида: ('Hello', 'World!'). Как получить в выводе: Hello World! без кавычек и скобок?
Кортеж выводится из БД через цикл. 
Метод .join c " " выводит (' H e l l o', 'W o r l d')

Comment: `print( ' '.join( ('Hello', 'World!') ) )`

Comment: Идёт разделение между букв, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: А это точно кортеж? Может, это строка? (узнать тип можно функцией `type`)

Comment: Да, я уже проверил, это кортеж.

Comment: `print( ''.join([i+' ' for i in ' '.join( ('Hello', 'World!'))] ))`

Comment: @S.Nick у вас выводит побуквено, а надо то словами

Comment: И без скобок с кавычками.

Comment: @0x00 покажите еще раз, что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: `print( ' '.join([ ''.join(i.split()) for i in (' H e l l o', 'W o r l d')]) )`

Comment: @finally вы мой первый комментарий видели?

Comment: @S.Nick Hello World! без скобок и кавычек на выходе.

Comment: @0x00 я вам именно это и написал в ответе

Comment: `print(*('Hello', 'World!'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно так

```py
x = ('Hello', 'World!')
print(' '.join([i for i in x]))
```

пробелим каждое слово в кортеже