# вывод кортежа без скобок

Tags: python, list, join, print, кортежи

у меня есть список с кортежами
`coins = [(230, 150), (730, 150)]`
я вывожу элемент этого списка:
`print(coins[0])`
ожидаемый результат:

`230, 150`

результат который я получаю:

`(230, 150)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Убрать одинарные кавычки из кортежа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1035018/%d0%a3%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку самый лаконичный способ уже предложен, то устроим небольшую анархию

**Перевод в строку без первого и последнего символа**

```py
print(str(coins[0])[1:-1])
```

**Использование f-string**

```py
print(f"{coins[0][0]}, {coins[0][1]}")
```

**Конкатенация строки из членов итерируемого объекта**

```py
print(", ".join(str(item) for item in coins[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно применить оператор распаковки итерируемого объекта (здесь — кортежа) в аргументы, лежащие в объекте — префиксном * (вот [здесь](https://tproger.ru/translations/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/) инфа по этому и не только). Он как раз распакует Ваш кортеж до `230, 150` без скобок.

```py
print(*coins[0])

---

230, 150 # скобочки исчезли
```

Answer (score 0):

Может как-то так?

```py
for v in coins[0]:
    print(v)
```